# Qt : program crashes when I try to modify class member

Tags: c++, qt

So program crashes anytime I try to change _studentsQuantity. But if I assign variable in constructor all is OK.
Firstly I tried to assign _studentsQuantity from QTextStream but it doesn't work.
This is function to load data from file:

```
    bool journalManager::loadFile(const QString& fileName)
    {
       QFile file(fileName);
       if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) )
       {
           QTextStream fin(&file);
           _studentsQuantity = 6; //fin.readLine().toInt();

           file.close();
           return true;
       }

   return false;

    }
```

And this this class implementation:

```
class journalManager
{
public:
    journalManager();
    bool loadFile(const QString& fileName);
    void writeToFile(QString fileName) const;
    void updateTableMarks(int subjectNumber);
    void updateTableStudents();
    void updateComboBoxSubjects();
    void setTableMarks(QTableWidget *tableMarks) { _tableMarks = tableMarks; }
    void setTableStudents(QTableWidget *tableStudents) { _tableStudents = tableStudents; }
    void setComboBoxSubjects(QComboBox *comboBoxSubjects) { _comboBoxSubjects = comboBoxSubjects; }
private:
    typedef struct studentStruct
    {
       QString _surname;
       QString _name;

       QString data() { return _surname + _name; }
    } student;

    QVector<student> _students;
    QVector<QString> _subjects;
    QVector<QVector<QVector<int> > > _marks;
    int _marksQuantity;
    int _subjectsQuantity;
    int _studentsQuantity;
    QTableWidget *_tableMarks;
    QTableWidget *_tableStudents;
    QComboBox *_comboBoxSubjects;

};
```

Also I tried to debug and got message that there is a segmentation fault

This is how I use an object of type journalManager

```
void MainWindow::open()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open file"), "../ElelectronicJournal", tr("Text files (*.txt)") );
    if(!fileName.isNull() )
    {
        if(manager->loadFile(fileName) )
            statusBar()->showMessage(tr("File opened"));
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem probably lies in how you're using the `journalManager` object. You'll need to post more code showing that.

Comment: I use pointer to journalManager in class mainwindow

Comment: Then your problem is almost certainly that the pointer is no longer valid when you use it. Be it null or a dangling pointer. Try using valgrind and that might help you out.

Comment: Oh, I put pointer in public field and it works

Comment: Changing the pointer from private/protected to public shouldn't fix this. That's a very strong indication you're doing something wrong, and this change is only masking that.

Comment: Thank you, I just change pointer to simple object and it works. Before I used null pointer  as you say.

Comment: Glad to help. Using a normal object is a better approach anyway.